# How to get the options?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a practice session. In the view page each question and the corresponding options has to be displayed.I am able to get all the questions but not the options. I think I need to pass each question id for displaying the corresponding options. But I'm not able to get that. Somebody plz help to get the options according to the question.

Controller code:

```
function index() {


    $data['qn']  = $this->questions_model->questions_list();
    foreach($data['qn'] as $row){ 
    $qs_id = $row->qid;
    $data['qn']['$qs_id']= $this->questions_model->option_list($qs_id);
    $data['qq_id'] =  $data['qn']['$qs_id'];


  //print_r($data['qq_id']);
}

    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view') . '/header', $data);
    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view') . '/questions_list', $data);
    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view') . '/footer', $data);

}
```

Model code:

```
function questions_list() { 

$this->db->select('qbank.*,question_category.category_name');
    $this->db->from('qbank');
$this->db->join('question_category','qbank.cid = question_category.cid');
$query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function option_list($qs_id){
$this->db->select('option_value');
$this->db->from('q_options');
$this->db->where('qid',$qs_id);

$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
return $query->result();
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

view code:

```
<form id="profilefrm" class="sky-form" name="profilefrm" method="post">
<ol>
<?php  foreach($qn as $row){ ?>
<li>
<?php echo $row->question; ?>
<ol type="A">
<?php foreach($qq_id as $rows){ ?>
<li><?php echo $rows->option_value; ?></li>
<?php } ?>                              
</ol>  
</li>

<?php } ?>
</ol>
</form>
```

Comment: there is no action method on here `<form id="profilefrm" class="sky-form" name="profilefrm" method="post">`

Comment: ok i added this <form id="profilefrm" action ="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/questions/index" class="sky-form" name="profilefrm" method="post"> but still the same :/

Comment: so where is ur submit button??

Comment: this is just a practice session. There is no submit button and no result. Just the user can view the question and options . I will create a button to view the answer so that the answer will be displayed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller

```
'foreach($data['qn'] as $row){ 
 $qs_id = $row->qid;
 $data['qn']['$qs_id']= $this->questions_model->option_list($qs_id);'
```

model

```
  'function option_list($qs_id){
  $this->db->select('option_value');
  $this->db->from('q_options');
  $this->db->where('q_id','$qs_id');
 $this->db->limit(4);
$query = $this->db->get();
 if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
    return false;
} '
```

view

```
<li>
<?php echo $row->question; ?>
<ol type="A">
<?php 
$qs_id = $row->qid;
foreach($row['$qs_id'] as $rows){ ?>
<li><?php echo $rows->option_value; ?></li>
<?php } ?>                              
</ol>  
</li>'
```